# Signature vertification failed in Google Play purchase

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, rsa, google-play-console, phpseclib

I have a backend in PHP that integrates with Google Play services to verify a purchase made from an APP. The purchase info returns the receip and the signature, and I need to verify that the purchase is correct.

I receive:

```
{ 
   ...rest of the data,
   receipt": {
      "orderId":"...",
      "packageName": ...,
      "productId":" ...,
      "purchaseTime": ...,
      "purchaseState": 0,
      "purchaseToken": ...,
      "autoRenewing": true
   },
"signature": ...
}
```

And I use the public key located in the Google Play Console to verify the signature. I formatted it to PEM manually by adding the -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and -----END API KEY----. I also divided the lines into chunks of 64 and I have also verified that the public key corresponds to the correct project.

Finally I use the [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) library to perform the validation, but it keeps failing.

```
    $receipt= $transaction['receipt'];
    $rsa = new RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey(Yii::$app->params['public_key']);
    $verify = $rsa->verify(json_encode($receipt), $signature);
```

I encode the receipt because the verify method needs a string, but I am not sure of this step. I am doing this from a test environment, so the purchase is not real. I suspect that the public key is somehow not correct, but I got it from Development Tools > Services & APIs > Licensing and app billing. What could be wrong?

Comment: I have checked that the phpseclib expects a signature of lenght 256 but the one that Google Play returns has 341 chars.

Comment: I would say: post the signature you're trying to verify, the plaintext and post the key you're using to do the verification. As is, it seems quite likely to me that (1) the signature is base64 encoded (ie. you'd need to run it through `base64_decode` and (2) that Google is using PKCS1 padding whereas phpseclib defaults to PSS padding for signatures. You can change the signature padding to PKCS1 by doing `$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);`

Comment: @neubert Seems like you nailed it, thanks! If you post it as a answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say: post the signature you're trying to verify, the plaintext and post the key you're using to do the verification. As is, it seems quite likely to me that (1) the signature is base64 encoded (ie. you'd need to run it through `base64_decode` and (2) that Google is using PKCS1 padding whereas phpseclib defaults to PSS padding for signatures. You can change the signature padding to PKCS1 by doing `$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);`